# Upload multiple files with aws s3 with presigned URL using python and angular

Tags: python, angular, typescript, amazon-s3

i am getting presign url from python server and upload images through for loop after for loop i save file name in database with add function but if i try more than 100 files all files are not uploaded to s3  bucket

PYTHON:

```
def generate_get_presigned_url(self, bucket_name, object_key, expiration_time=3600):
        try:
            url = self.s3.generate_presigned_url(
                'get_object',
                Params={'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': object_key,"ResponseContentDisposition": 'attachment'},
                ExpiresIn=expiration_time,
            )
            return url
        except NoCredentialsError:
            print("Credentials not available")
```

ANGULAR:

```
const files = fil.files;
    console.log(files);

    let list = []
    
    for  (const file of files) {
      const formDataObj = new FormData();
      list.push(file.name);

      // formDataObj.append('files', files[0]);
      this.pricingService.get_put_url({ filename: `${this.user}/${file.name}` }).subscribe({
        next: (data: any) => {
          console.log(data);
          this.pricingService.save_files(data.presigned_url, file)


        }
      })
    }
    this.pricingService.add({ "files": list, "collection_id": this.selected_collection._id, "user_id": localStorage.getItem("User") }).subscribe({
      next: (data: any) => {
        console.log(data);
        this.onCollection(this.selected_collection)

      }
    })
```

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: how to ask a good question:
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)